# Is my analysis of the selection sort correct?

Tags: sorting, big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Hobbyist here, I'm reading CLS and I'm having trouble with the analysis stuff. It's mostly that I'm not very good at figuring out summations from different kinds of loops and stuff. Anyway, I wrote up an explanation and some example code to show you what I mean. I think it's right, but I'm getting mixed messages from a lot of different sources. First off, here's some example code in C++, you'll notice that it contains a reference to an integer n and several incrementations of it. Those were put there to count how many times each statement took as a way to check it.

```
int *intSelSort(int a[], int size, int &n){
    int i, k, in; 
    for(int j = 0; ++n && j < size -1; j++){
        k = a[j]; 
        n++;
        for(int i = j+1; ++n && i < size; i++)

            if(++n && a[i] < k){
                k = a[i];
                in = i;
            } 

        a[in] = a[j];
        a[j] = k; 
        n+=2;
    }
    return a; 
}
```

This example, when used with an array of length 5 leaves n with a value of 41. The counts are all removed save for the one in the innermost for loop's condition, the count is 14. That's important for later.

Anyway, CLS does things a little differently, starting with the fact that it uses pseudocode and array indices beginning at 1. I wrote some to mirror their work

```
//[1][2][3][4][5]
//Highest j is 4, i is 5

int k, index;                           //O(1)
n = A.Size                              //O(1)
for j = 1, j < n, j++ do                //O(N)
    k = A[j]                            //O(N - 1)
    for i = j + 1, i <= n, i++ do       //O((n^2 + n - 2)/2)
            if(A[i] < k)                //O((n^2 - n)/2)    
                k = A[i]                //O(c)
                index = i               //O(c)
    A[index] = A[j]                     //O(N - 1)
    A[j] = k                            //O(N - 1)
```

(If n = 5, first it makes 5 comparisons, counting the extra)
(Then 4, 3, 2, 1)

2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (n - 0) comparisons

3, 4, 5, 6 (n - 1) comparisons

4, 5, 6 (n - 2) comparisons

5, 6 (n - 3) comparisons

[j = 5, i = 6], exits for loop, no comparison

(n - 0) + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + (n - 3) = 4n - 6 comparisons, 14.

---

**Or more generally**,

sum(n - N)_(0 -> N = n - 2) =

sum(n)*(0 -> N = n - 2) - sum(N)*(0 -> N = n - 2) =

n(n - 2 + 1) - ((n - 1)(n - 2))/2 = (n^2 + n - 2)/2

If n = 5, this yields 14. Exactly the number of steps in the test.

---

**For the if in that for loop**,

sum(n - N - 1)_(0 - > N = n - 2)

= (n^2 + n - 2)/2 - sum(1)_(0 -> N = n - 2)

= (n^2 + n - 2)/2 - (n - 1) = (n^2 - n)/2, or in this case, 10 compares

Testing the inner most if statement alone also yielded 10 compares.

---

C is dependent on whether the if statement is ever true. 
Case one: The list is already sorted, the if statement will never be 
      true, so the statements in there will never be called.

Case two: The list is reverse sorted, the if statements are called 
      floor(N/2) times?

5 4 3 2 1
1 4 3 2 5
1 2 3 4 5

9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 9
1 2 7 6 5 4 3 8 9
1 2 3 6 5 4 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Are there other cases in which the if statement is true more times?
Is there a way to prove that the if statement's sub statements are 
of time complexity n or less, so I can ignore them? Are they O(n)? 
Did I make any drastic errors here? I've seen websites with different
summation formulas for this, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think your analysis is correct.

To your question at the end:
For sequence `n, 1, 2, ..., n-1` the if statement is n-1 times true (and n-1 times two elements are swaped.)
for the reversed order it is not floor(N/2). It is

> N-1 + N-3 + N-5 + ... + 0 = Σ<sub>i=0,..⌊N/2⌋</sub> N-1-2⋅i ≈ ((N-1) ⋅ N)/2

and ⌊N/2⌋ times two elements are swaped.

But it is not importend how often the if statement is true, due to the O(1) complexity of the actions in the body of the if statement. Your analysis is very precise. This is not necessary, if you  arte using the big-O notation. Let me simplify your example:

```
int k, index;                      // O(1)
n = A.Size                         // O(1)
for j = 1, j < n, j++ do           // O(N)  - runs n-1 times
    k = A[j]                       // O(1)  - takes only 1 step but is executet O(N) times.
    for i = j + 1, i <= n, i++ do  // O(N)  - the first run takes n-1 steps    -+  
            if(A[i] < k)           // O(1)  - this can be evaluated in 1 step   |- together 1 to 3 steps. So the whole if block is in O(1).
                k = A[i]           // O(1)  - this is at worst 1 more step     -+
                index = i          // O(1)  - this also
    A[index] = A[j]                // O(1)  - one step executet O(N) times
    A[j] = k                       // O(1)  - one step executet O(N) times
```

Notice: This are not overall complexitys, but only the complexity of each item of the code by it self.

Now you only have to multiply the nested complexitys and you get an overall complexity of

> O(N) ⋅ O(N) ⋅ O(1) = O(N<sup>2</sup>).

If you are interested in a more precise analysis you can reduce the complexity of the nested for loop to O(N-i) and sum this up for i from 1 to N-1.

> O(N-1) + O(N-2) + ... + O(N-N+1) = O((N-1)⋅N/2) = O(N<sup>2</sup>)

Notice also tht the big-O notations and the complexity of algorithms can not directly translated into execution time or number of steps an algorithm exactly will do.